# How to form_alter fields attached to an unlimited field collection?

Tags: 7, entities

Here are 2 unsuccessful experiments I've done:

```
<?php

/**
 * My first attempt with implementing hook_form_alter.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'MYNODETYPE_node_form':
      foreach ($form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)) {

          // None of these work:
          $form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'][$delta]['field_SOMEFIELD']['und']['#default_value'] = 'test';
          $form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'][$delta]['field_SOMEFIELD']['#default_value'] = 'test';

          $form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'][$delta]['field_SOMEFIELD']['und']['#value'] = 'test';
          $form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'][$delta]['field_SOMEFIELD']['#value'] = 'test';

        }
      }
  }
}


/**
 * My second attempt implementing hook_field_widget_form_alter.
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION' && $context['instance']['bundle'] == 'MYNODETYPE') {
    // These don't work either:
    $element['field_SOMEFIELD']['#value'] = 'test';
    $element['field_SOMEFIELD']['#default_value'] = 'test';

    $element['field_SOMEFIELD']['und']['#value'] = 'test';
    $element['field_SOMEFIELD']['und']['#default_value'] = 'test';
  }
}
```

How can I alter the form API elements on fields attached to a field collection?

**PS:** The hook functions are running fine. The issue is that the form API values I set do not make any change on the loaded form.

Comment: do the functions actually run? and does it make it through the if statements?

Comment: @Geoff yes, they do. The only issue is that the new array elements I set seem to be ignored by the form API.

Comment: I took a look at a field collection I use via dpm, and it is layed out like this: $element[field][und][0]][value][default value].  Are you sure about the array structure for the fields you are trying to access?

Comment: Nope, I am not :-D. I am trying out your suggestion.

Comment: @Geoff you are the man. $element[field][und][0]][value][default value] is the way to go. Thank you

Please answer the question and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Please be aware the "und" part should be replaced by `[LANGUAGE_NONE]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the array to make sure you are using the correct names and structure.  You can use dpm() from the devel module to check this.

Both hook_form_alter or hook_field_widget_form_alter allow you to alter field collection child field form elements.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'MYNODETYPE_node_form':
      foreach ($form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)) {

          $form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'][$delta]['field_SOMEFIELD']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'default value';
          $form['field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION']['und'][$delta]['field_SOMEFIELD']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = 'value';

        }
      }
  }
}
```

The following will also work:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter.
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION' && $context['instance']['bundle'] == 'MYNODETYPE') {

    $element['field_SOMEFIELD']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = 'value';
    $element['field_SOMEFIELD']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'default value';

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the advantages are but you can also use `form_set_value($form["field_MYFIELDCOLLECTION"][LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta]['field_SOMEFIELD'], array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('value' => 123346))), $form_state);
` at this point instead of setting the $element, but i think it does the same thing.