# Unable to set field collection field value on form validation

Tags: 7, entities

The question might look similar to [How to form_alter fields attached to an unlimited field collection?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118347/how-to-form-alter-fields-attached-to-an-unlimited-field-collection) but I am more concerned about "values not saved after custom validation"

I have a field collection "field_assignments" consists of:

- field_check_user: A user reference field
- field_assigned_booklets: An integer field
- field_total_cost: A hidden field (used in validation handler for calculation)

I have content type "marking" having this field collection (unlimited values) along with a field_rate. I have alter node editing form and defined a custom validation which is working fine. The problem is that I cannot update the field collection item "field_total_cost" value in custom validation function. The validation function is

```
function _additional_validate($form, &$form_state) {
   // If rate is set to 100 and assigned booklets are 5; this should result 500
   $tc = $form_state['values']['field_assignments']['und'][0]
         ['field_assigned_booklets']['und'][0]['value'] * $form_state['values']['field_rate']['und'][0]['value'];

   $form_state['values']['field_assignments']['und'][0]['field_total_cost']['und'][0]['value'] = $tc;
}
```

If I dpm $form_state, I can see that the ['field_total_cost']['und'][0]['value'] is updated (see image below) but when the node is submitted, it does not show that value in node view and does not save that value in the database. How can I save a value in field collection field?

[image]

I tried form_set_value() but couldn't understand how to set value for compounded fields (field collection in this case, I'll be thankful if someone can show how can I construct that "#parent" stuff with these fields). The code with form_set_value() I tried:

```
 // testing on a single field - works perfectly
 form_set_value($form['field_rate']['und'][0]['value'], $tc, $form_state);

 // does not update the value
 form_set_value($form['field_assignments']['und'][0]['field_total_cost']['und'][0]['value'], $tc, $form_state);
```

P.S: I have written 'und' instead LANGUAGE_NONE for ease

Answer (score 1):

Use [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) instead of doing it yourself! Don't use `_validate`, just use `_compute`.

- Change field_total_cost to a computed field, saving as decimal.
- Create a custom module and add the following (much clearer than using Computed Fields settings inputs - yuk)

Do something like the following :

```
/**
 * Computed field for - field_total_cost
 */
function computed_field_field_total_cost_compute(&$entity_field, $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items) {
  $tot   = 0;
  $books = 0;
  $rate  = 0;
  if (isset($entity->field_assigned_booklets[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
    $books = $entity->field_assigned_booklets[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
  if (isset($entity->field_rate[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
    $rate = $entity->field_rate[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
  $tot = $books * $rate;
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = number_format((float) $tot, 2, '.', '');
}

/**
 * Display for - field_total_cost
 */
function computed_field_field_total_cost_display($field, $entity_field_item, $entity_lang, $langcode, $entity) {
  return '£' . number_format($entity_field_item['value'], 2);
}
```

I obviously don't know what your calculations are like but you get the idea.
This will calculate and populate the Total Cost field per field collection.

**OR**

If you still want to do it on validate you (afaict) can't do it on node_validate but you can on a field validate. So you need to add a custom validate function to your Field Collection field, then it should work as you think.

Add a custom validate callback on `hook_field_widget_form_alter`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // Add custom validation hooks for Field Collections.
  if ($context['field']['field_name'] == 'field_assignments') {
    array_unshift($element['#element_validate'], 'MYMODULE_field_assignments_validate');
  }
}
```

Create the custom validate function and set the value similar to how you suggested

```
/**
 * Custom validate function for field_assignments.
 *
 *  @see MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_field_assignments_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {    
  form_set_value($form["field_assignments"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_total_cost'], array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('value' => 123.456))), $form_state);
}
```

I obliviously left out any logic in this example, but you get the idea :)